# mac cursor not turning into the finger when hovering over clickable elements

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, monterey

I have a MacBook Pro 16 inch Monterey with the m1 chip.

I am not sure what I did. But it no longer changes into the finger pointer when hovering over clickable elements

Comment: Which clickable elements? For example the pointer does not change to a pointing finger when hovering over the window controls (red/yellow/green dots) or any other control in the top of a window. The pointing finger is usually for links on a web page...

Comment: Even on the browsers, the pointer is also not changing when hovering over links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pointer size is set to any value other than the default ‘normal’ size, the pointer does not change from the arrow. This is intended behaviour.

Check your pointer size is at ‘normal’ in System Settings → Accessibility → Display → Pointer Size.

There also appears to be a macOS bug where changing the pointer size back to ‘normal’ does not reset this behaviour for a short/random period. Logging out and back in fixes this.